Ad blocker not blocking ads when I log into YouTube with my Google account
For the past three days, I've encountered an issue where ads suddenly started appearing on YouTube even though uBlock Origin was enabled. After some investigation using different browsers (Chrome, Brave, Thorium, and Firefox), I concluded that uBlock Origin and other ad blockers work perfectly until I log into my Google account. When I sign into my Google account, the blockers stop working on YouTube.
I tried using a different Google account and didn't experience any issues; everything worked fine. I also disabled all other extensions and still had the same problem. Does anyone know what might be causing this? Is there a setting within the Google account that I might have accidentally enabled, allowing ads to bypass uBlock Origin, or has Google started targeting individual accounts?

Yes, there have been numerous mentions of this, lately. https://adguard.com/en/blog/ad-blockers-youtube-ban.html, https://community.brave.com/t/suddenly-getting-ad-blockers-are-not-allowed-on-youtube/507177, https://www.standard.co.uk/news/tech/youtube-blocking-ad-blockers-watching-videos-b1080501.html

It is worth noting that alternate YouTube clients may do better blocking these ads than browsers and plugins. ReVanced, on Android, for instance, is still serving ad-free videos.

See also this article from Gizmodo yesterday claiming that  YouTube is experimenting with server-side ad injection

Adblockers versus ad networks is always a cat-and-mouse game.
Given that the ad networks are highly profitable and those running them are paid, that is an advantage over the often volunteer efforts behind the best adblockers. Also, given that the best adblockers are largely open source, the developers for the ad networks are able to see the code being used to block their ads and find ways to make it more and more difficult for their content to be blocked.
It is normal for these products to vary in their efficacy. The normal process is that the ad networks release some new ad method and their ads get through, and then a few days later the adblockers figure out how to block the new methods.
I'm trying to emphasize that this is normal.
As a user, you sit and wait. You can check the individual forums for the adblockers, but I recommend NOT posting "HALP, IT'S BROKEN!!!" because they already know it's not working.
As a contributor, you could join the adblocker developer community, though probably wait for an easier period to join, as your joining may require those dedicated teams to take attention away from the immediate fix to hold your hand until you're up to speed and actually contributing.

You could try the following:

update your filters by entering uBlock Origin control panel through its icon -> Cogwheels icon  -> Filter list - this very often fixes YouTube problems for me, despite having automated updates on. It seems they can get delayed from time to time.
turn the extension off and on - this rarely also refreshed the plugin into a state in which some blocking started working again
purge cache for YouTube (Ctrl / Shift + F5 on their homepage) or even the entire browser - personally I didn't have to do it, but it's recommended by a lot of people

Since YouTube started messing with adblockers last year, I never had a downtime of blocking, as long as I followed these steps.

Your Google account settings may need to be adjusted too. When signed in to Google, head over to "Manage your Google account".
Next, to "Data and privacy" at the left menu. Now this here, Google keeps all your data of activities, personalisations and whatnot. Shut 'em all off. Including the ads personalisation. If you have had the Personalized Ads on all the while from the "MyAds Center", you may want to clear every single trace of ad companies that have tracked you in the list through Google. I'm not sure if it is the same as many years before, but when i dug through, i had hundreds of ad companies linked to my info in that settings and i deleted them one by one tediously before. After which i shut off the ads personalization and that was that. Never saw through it ever after updates from Google.
Clear/delete history manually from time to time although there are options given to automatically do it periodically. (I don't trust that automation from Google personally.) Although you could pause history, just make a check from time to time too over that setting because from my horrific experience, Google did revert my settings from pause to unpause automatically too when i wasn't aware! With me, I do have an alternate YT to keep track of any changes from Google over my settings... just as a backup 'notifier' via mobile.
Ublock does give you some advantage over YT through PC but the drawback is that you may need to keep disabling the cosmetic filterings switch there in order to use the YT filters depending on your search needs and then reenable them when you want Ublock to continue filtering the rest. When you disable the cosmetic filtering switch, sponsored ads videos appear in your search. If you have otherwise, your Ublock may need updated with latest filters. Or you could use the picker mode or zap elements off manually but then of course, you need to have enabled the cosmetic filtering switch first in order to see the difference it makes.
With extensions, depending on your browser, you could hop over to TamperMonkey/GreasyFork to download independent scripts that could be used based on your needs. Some work the way it is supposed to and some not to your exact needs but there's a lot of scripts available to tweak things deeply about.
There's another simple thing you may need to do in order to mess up Google's fast snooping activity too. And that is, clear your cookies from your browser before activating back with your updated blockers. That way, you could reset the walls before it could pass through the newer setup.
The least you could do meantime.

Welcome to this site. There's a lot of what is at best tangentially-related commentary and story in this question, enough that it is obscuring a focused answer to the question posed. Please note that this site is not an open discussion forum, but a "Question and Answer" site, where specific questions can receive specific answers. If you do have an answer that differs substantially from those already posed, please EDIT your post to use some common formatting (such as paragraphs), remove the narrative and portions of the question unrelated to what was asked.

Ohh? And your say is that i have not answered it? You don't see the paragraph? Unrelated? Kindly show me where it is unrelated, so i could gladly remove it.
